# Tamil font in mysql

Tags: mysql

Tamil Font display is incorrect because it seems, that is how letters are encrypted by the system. Which is revealed when any word in Tamil is segmented.

**Ex**. :

> படிகஅமைப்பு  = பட +  ிகஅமைப்பு instead of படிகஅமைப்பு =  படி +
>   கஅமைப்பு

However I kept trying changing font to "Latha" in Excel, then exported to MySQL but result remained the same. How to Overcome the issue I am using Heidi SQL.

Comment: Have you set the encoding to UTF8 in your database?

Answer (score 0):

படிகஅமைப்பு is 11 byte string. if you want to segment only first 2 character(படி), then you need to segment first 3 byte. because டி is stored as ட + ி